Receiver Swap Long vs Short the rate?
today during my interview I was asked if the receive fixed side of the swap is long the interest rate or short the interest rate. My answer was short the interest rate as this side benefits when rates go down (similar to long bond position). But I am not sure what is the correct answer and i think this question is ambigious. Can someone explain me?

You have the economics correct in your mind.  However the market language is generally that 'long rates' is the same direction as 'long bonds', so you might have answered incorrectly.  However if you explained your thinking, you might not be faulted.

I definitely would have clarified the direction in the answer to ensure clear communication. "long rates" "long bonds" same or different to different types of traders.

The interviewer looked like the answer was wrong. Is it just about the market language? Because I was thinking about it for a while and I do not see how being a fixed rate receiver can be equivalent to being long the interest rate, as you benefit when rates fall.

One quite annoying thing about using jargon is that people sometimes (ab)use it to mean completely opposite things. As @Attack68 said, to most people "long interest rates" and/or "long credit" usually means the same as being long a (fixed coupon / credit-risky) bond - i.e. betting that the interest rates and/or credit spreads will tighten. However I have also seen some people use exactly the same terms to mean that they bet that the interest rate or credit spreads would increase, e.g. long 2Y swap rate, but short 10Y swap rate, or long (some name) CDS protection.

If I were asked such question, I might respond that receiving fixed is like buying a fixed-coupon bond, betting that the interest rates would decrease and the price of the bond would go up. I hate jargon and the people who use it. :)

I googled to see the usage  on the web https://www.analystforum.com/t/interest-rate-futures-position-take-on-bond-or-rate/73878 "When they say they are long the rate, i think rate goes up, they make money.  I really think it needs to be explicitly stated what the underlying is" https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/9370 "Interest rate wise, issuer is long interest rate as he has agreed to pay a fixed rate against the floating rate received on the note notional." https://konvexity.com/similarity-and-dissimilarity-of-swap-contracts-with-a-series-of-forward-contracts (cont)

"effectively one party that is long bond is short interest rate (as bond prices are indirectly proportional to the price) and the other party that is short bond is long interest rate."  https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/pyjge8/eli5_how_does_an_interest_rate_swap_agreement/ "let's say a bank that trades and is overall long interest rates " The CFA usage seems to be the opposite of most others'. To avoid confusion, avoid such ambiguous language, although you don't need to call it out in a job interview.

Thank you guys for your answers. I just hope the interviewer understood me right, because I am sure she believed it was a wrong answer. Seems like it could be the wrong answer only based on a market jargon but not the common sense.

And then she asked me which leg has higher duration? I said the fixed leg has higher duration. And after that she asked her question again "so is fixed receiver short or long the interest rate. And again I said short the rate and she looked at me as I had to change my mind :)

Expressing the interest rate sensitivities of interest rate swap's legs in terms of "duration" indicates that you may want to trade with her, but you don't want to work with her. :)

Found an good post on jargon https://fermatslastspreadsheet.com/2011/11/30/mine-yours/ Cant believe I actually got asked 2-3 questions from this list and they actually mean the opposite of what the text book says. Do you think its right to test knowledge of jargon on interviews rather than actual meaning?

I agree these questions are unfair to newcomers, but the firm might be tying to identify people with meaningful work experience, in addition to book knowledge. It is not just useless jargon but everyday terminology that they use.
